# How can you iterate two lists in python and repeat the smaller in order of the index?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to iterate through the list 'grid' so I can get a pattern that prints each list in order of index repeating itself when it gets to the last list in the 'grid' list up until it is the same as the number in pri_score.

I don't get any error message when i run it in the terminal.

Edit:
I've got it working now this is what I did.

```
pri_score = input("What did you score? ")
print mark(pri_score)
ite = 0

grid = [['0','0','1','0','0'],
['0','1','1','1','0'],
['1','1','1','1','1'],
['0','1','1','1','0'],
['0','0','1','0','0'],
['0','0','0','0','0']]

grid_index = 0

while ite < pri_score:
    if grid_index == 5:
        grid_index = 0
    else:
        grid_index += 1
        print grid[grid_index]
    ite += 1
```

Comment: Is the `pri_score` intended to be a negative number?

Comment: Thanks but I've done it now, I'll repost the working version now.

Answer (score 0):

What i think, it should be:

```
while ite < pri_score:     # less than instead of greater than
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might make your life easier:

```
pri_score = input("What did you score? ")
print mark(pri_score)

grid = [['0','0','1','0','0'],
['0','1','1','1','0'],
['1','1','1','1','1'],
['0','1','1','1','0'],
['0','0','1','0','0'],
['0','0','0','0','0']]

for i in range(pri_score):
    print grid[ i % len(grid) ]
```

The basic trick for the repeating pattern that you want is the modulo operator %, and avoiding the manual iterator variables is a standard idiom in python.